# Would caustic soda destroy a rubber gasket under a sink?

Tags: plumbing, drain, kitchen-sink, sealant

Today I made the mistake of pouring caustic soda down a kitchen waste-pipe to unblock it. Despite reading that it's safe on plastic pipes, it created a terrible leak between the pipe and the underside of the sink. I assume it ate right through the rubber gasket.

Is this to be expected, or does it sound like the sink was badly fitted? I know how corrosive caustic soda is, but it seems like it's pretty common for exactly this purpose.

Comment: What is "sealant"? Modern sink drains don't usually require plumber's putty or caulk. They typically use rubber gaskets.

Comment: Perhaps it was rubber that was destroyed then. Would caustic soda do that? The sealant I used in the emergency was general bathroom caulk.

Comment: Does that mean latex caulk, silicone, or a blend? You're asking a specific question, so we need specific details.

Comment: I'd tell you if I had it to hand, but it's not where I am. I'll post back with more info later.

Comment: a reaction with gunk in the sink could have released enough heat to melt the pipe, but it's hard to see it eating through something legitimately used/sold for plumbing.

Comment: This is what I thought and the bottle contained no warning. Sink is quite old though ~10 yrs. If it was indeed a rubber seal, perhaps it was worn?

Comment: But it's not *rubber* rubber, it's a kind of plastic.  Also, "10 years" is not old!  The way to be sure is dismantle it and pull the offending gasket.  Next trip would then be to a hardware store.  My local one stocks every gasket that has ever existed.